# What technique facebook use to notify users?

Tags: facebook, notifications

I'm just being curious. Does anyone know what technique/how facebook notification works? Because, when ever someone post a comment on my wall it appears in the notification, it happens instantly. It looks to me, server sends notification to client instead of client dialling to server every such amount of time.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: No idea. Why not use Fiddler to look at the HTTP traffic?

Comment: good idea, but I don't think it'll help you to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, their online chat uses [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (via [MochiWeb](http://github.com/mochi/mochiweb)) so I wouldn't be surprised if notifications are handled in a similar way.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have found another article @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification