# How can I refresh a page for all logged in users (collaborative editing) using JavaScript, jQuery and HTML?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want the action to be automatically reflected for all the logged in users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to poll the server every few seconds or so. Then the server can respond with instructions to the browsers of all users visiting your site (or a selected few) in near real-time.

You may also want to consider [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Ajax_with_long_polling) instead of the above, to reduce the latency without increasing the frequency of the polls.

Quoting [Comet Daily: The Long-Polling Technique](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/15/the-long-polling-technique/):

> The long-polling Comet technique is a technique that optimizes traditional polling to reduce latency.
>
> Traditional polling sends an `XMLHttpRequest` to the server in fixed intervals. For example, open a new `XMLHttpRequest` every 15 seconds, receive an immediate response, and close the connection.
>
> Long-polling sends a request to the server, but a response is not returned to the client until one is available. As soon as the connection is closed, either due to a response being received by the client or if a request times out, a new connection is initiated. The result is a significant reduction in latency because the server usually has a connection established when it is ready to return information to return to the client.

In addition to the above, I also suggest that you check out the accepted answer to the following Stack Overflow post for a detailed description of the long polling technique:

- [How does facebook, gmail send the real time notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification)