# Server polling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

What are some good practices for polling a server with JavaScript for
an application that needs to refresh data very rapidly? I'm using jQuery for front-end and Java Spring Framework for backend.

Example of refreshed data could be list of items that are getting updated very rapidly (every 1 second).

Comment: Define very rapidly. Once a minute? Once every ten seconds? Once every second? What kind of data?

Comment: Every 1 second and data would text and maybe some html in very small amounts

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may want to use [jQuery's Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to poll the server every second or so. Then the server can respond with instructions to the browser in near real-time.

You can also consider [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Ajax_with_long_polling) instead of the above, to reduce the latency without increasing the frequency of the polls.

Quoting [Comet Daily: The Long-Polling Technique](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/15/the-long-polling-technique/):

> The long-polling Comet technique is a technique that optimizes traditional polling to reduce latency.
>
> Traditional polling sends an `XMLHttpRequest` to the server in fixed intervals. For example, open a new `XMLHttpRequest` every 15 seconds, receive an immediate response, and close the connection.
>
> Long-polling sends a request to the server, but a response is not returned to the client until one is available. As soon as the connection is closed, either due to a response being received by the client or if a request times out, a new connection is initiated. The result is a significant reduction in latency because the server usually has a connection established when it is ready to return information to return to the client.

In addition to the above, I also suggest that you check out the accepted answer to the following Stack Overflow post for a detailed description of the long polling technique:

- [How does facebook, gmail send the real time notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification)

Answer (score 4):

As of 2018 you should use the fetch function with promise syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
  fetch("your_serverside_script.php") // Any output from the script will go to the "result" div
  .then(response => response.text())
  .catch(error => document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = error)
  .then(response => document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response)
}, 1000); // Poll every 1000ms
</script>

<div id="result">result will appear here</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I [second Daniel's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583203/server-polling-with-javascript/3583240#3583240) to use long-poll or push. Check out

- [CometD Bayeux Ajax Push](http://cometd.org/)

> CometD is a scalable HTTP-based event routing bus that uses a Ajax Push technology pattern known as Comet. The term 'Comet' was coined by Alex Russell in his post Comet: Low Latency Data for the Browser.

They have a page explaining how to get that work with Spring:

- http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-java/server/services/integration-spring