# Adding an open chat log to a HTML5 Website?

Tags: javascript, css, html, livechat

How can I add a chat section to my website using HTML5, Javascript, and CSS. I want it so I assign a user a random chat username and when they type a message in a textbox it will then display in a log of all the user messages. The data will be temporary so the log should only show like 50 messages or so. How can I make this happen and how can I store the data when i purchase a domain name? I am new to this language so any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might start out by investigating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890796/html5-websockets-for-realtime-chat-app. Also you will probably need a server setup that has a database solution if you wish to store the chats so that includes learning/using a serverside language such as java, php, node.js...

Comment: Hire a web developer ;-)

Comment: HAHAHA ya i wish i could