# Get Refesh Data From The Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pull-to-refresh

How can i get latest or fresh data from server (if in server happened new event (***for example*** there are 2 users x,y and x send messages to y and y get this message without refreshing page ) )?
I don't want to use setInterval because it repeats all message again and again. Is there any Technique that can i use for this ?
I heard about Ajax that technique need to send request to the server but i want  when happen an event in the server and webpage get it without refreshing..

Answer (score 1):

The first technique is the long polling, which sends request to the server and waits until the server sends something, for example the new message. You must re-send requests to the server each time you get a new message or your request is time out. This technique uses AJAX. 
Long polling PHP example - [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-to-implement-basic-long-polling)

The second is web sockets, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

[**this stackoverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890796/html5-websockets-for-realtime-chat-app) deals with the implementation of websocket.

[**socket.io**](http://socket.io/demos/chat/) has a demo of chat application.

Comment: Can i have some more details on websockets how its works and maybe a small exemple ? i saw a tut but i didnt understand that means  **var socket =new Websocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");**

Comment: What backend platform do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for bidirectional full duplex method then go for `WebSockets` but for just polling data from server you can use `Server Sent Event` as well. Adding reference links for both:

**WebSocket:**

http://html5demos.com/web-socket

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

[HTML5 Websockets for Realtime Chat app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890796/html5-websockets-for-realtime-chat-app)

**SSE:**

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

**Examples:**

SSE: http://demo.howopensource.com/sse/

Comment: what is difference between sse and websocket ?

Comment: @Aryan if you want to send and receive data from server then you need to use `WebSocket` (Chatting System) but if you want to just fetch data from server then go with `SSE` (Stock Exchange Terminal)

Comment: Can i have some more details on websockets how its works and a small  exemple ?

Comment: @Aryan added link for SSE example, I will add for WebSocket once I will find a good one.