# Android notification new article on wordpress

Tags: android

Hi guys i have a site with wordpress.
I have developed a android app with a webview. I want implement the notification of new article.

I want recive a notification when admin insert a new article...
how to solve?
what's the best solution for this?
Thank you!

Comment: do you not have any idea yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Ineffective: make a request to server to check for updates, either from Java code, or from Javascript.
Effective, but more difficult at first: GCM push notifications.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583203/server-polling-with-javascript) about Javascript solution. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) for push notifications.