# mvc c# jquery facebook-like notification (that number on the icon on top)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, comet

im trying to apply this kind of notification with my website. but was wondering if jquery should be the way to go? like every 5 seconds or something to refresh the part of the page if there are any new updates for the record?

or should i do this "Comet" thing that is detailed on this post?

[how to implement facebook like notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359773/how-to-implement-facebook-like-notification)

not really sure how to best go about it.

also, this notification will have a lot of refreshes on a specific day of the month when an event is happening so i'm not sure if hitting the dbase every few seconds is the best way? or is there even a difference if i just use comet (where it just recieves data withou request)?

Comment: Look at SignalR too. http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hit the DB every few seconds. You need to broadcast to the connected clients when a new notification is triggered (after you insert the notification in the DB)

You can do this easily with [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR) using Hubs. [Check out this documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) that shows how to broadcast only to specified clients.