# Facebook like Notification implementation in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jsf

I am using java and jsp for my project. I have developed a facebook like notification icon. I am doing a servlet URL call by jQuery. Servlet checks the value in DB and return the result. This call interval is 1 second. Ex.-

```
<div id="noti_Container">
    <a href="layoutMailbox.jsf"> 
        <img src="#{resource['images:Network.png']}"
        alt="Notifications" style="width: 25px;" />
</a>

<div id="check" class="noti_bubble">2</div>
    <script>
        var int=self.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
        function clock()
        {
            $.get('Servlet URL', function(responseText) {
                    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = responseText;
                    });
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

But this could be a "heavy" approach because it pings Servlet every second and doing the DB-interaction.

Is there any alternative to update count of Notifications if DB gets updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into ajax push solutions like [cometD](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/) or [websocket](http://www.websocket.org/) ([socket.io](http://socket.io/)). Using it you will 'push' data to the web browser if DB changes instead of pooling for changes.
Personally i tried websocket with good results but there can be issues with browser support.

Edit:

Check this article about [long polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery).
Just bumped into article about using [JSR 356](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api) (WebSocket).
There is similar question on stackoverflow: [how to implement facebook like notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359773/how-to-implement-facebook-like-notification)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that only the Java-Webapp conntects to the SQL-Database only, you better use the `java.util.Observable` and his GoF-Pattern, instead of ask the SQL-Server for a value you added in the last 1 second.

You also should not use `$.get`. Please use

```
function clock() {
  $('#check').reload('Servlet URL');
}
var int=self.setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

Because you are reloading an element by url. The Overhead is not necessary.

Comment: If you have multiple Tomcats with the same Application, you might like to use Queueing.

Comment: I implemented it, but its not updating. 
I will check for the Observable class. Thanks.