# using long polling with facebook graph API (for "real-time" notifications)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comet

I'm looking into implementing a web page to show the user's news feed with real-time updates, without using simple polling to the facebook servers.
after browsing through similar questions:

- [How to implement facebook line notification?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5359773/how-to-implement-facebook-like-notification)
- [How does facebook, gmail send the real time notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification)
- [Facebook notification system: Is it polling?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3788668/facebook-notification-system-is-it-polling)

As I understand - long polling (see [Comet model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)) is the most preferable way for me to achieve "push"-like events for when a new post is added to a user's feed.

I'm using javascript, on IE browser (6 and above), and the page is actually stored **locally**, and not on a server.

I'm aware of the [real-time updates subscription](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) graph API, but as I mentioned, my page will run locally, not on a server (not even localhost), that's why long polling seems so attractive at the moment.

**My question is** - does anyone know if and how long polling (or any other Comet model alternative) is available to use via the Facebook API? or maybe any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only long polling available is for the chat API.  Otherwise you're stuck with either real-time updates or using a javascript timer to poll.