# Potential race conditions when Promise used in subscriptions in Javascript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, observable

I recently dived into subscriptions of Subject/BehaviorSubject/ etc and I am looking for the goto approach when used in combinations with Promises.

Given is the example code below:

```js
firebase.user.subscribe((user: any | null) => {
    fs.readFile('path/to/file')
         .then((buf: Buffer) => {
             this.modifySomeData = buf;
         });
});
```

I subscribe to a Subject that triggers whenever the user logs in or out of their service. Whenever this happens, I read a file from disk. This `readFile` event could **potentially** take longer than the next "login/logout" event. Of course, I am in JS and in an asynchronous environment. This means, my user code is not multithreaded, but still, the 2nd user event and 2nd `readFile` could theoretically be faster than the first `readFile`.

1. First user event fired
2. First readFile is executed
3. Second user event is fired
4. Second readFile is executed
5. Second readFile is resolved <---
6. First readFile is resolved  <---

The order is mixed up. The silliest approach I could think of is to create a `uuid` before reading the file and check inside the promise if this is still the same. If it's not I discard the data.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have a process where older requests can be discarded i often keep a variable in scope to track the latest request and compare, similar to your UUID idea:

```
let lastRead: Promise<Buffer> | null = null;

firebase.user.subscribe((user: any | null) => {
    const read = lastRead = fs.readFile('path/to/file');
    read.then((buf: Buffer) => {
        if (read != lastRead)
            return;

        this.modifySomeData = buf;
    });
});
```

In this specific case, [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_readfile_options) also supports an abort signal. So you might also be able to abort the last request instead; you will still need to track it though.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted it as an answer as it goes very much into the direction I had with the `uuid`, except you use a different expression. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is to see if your event generation logic could handle waiting for event handling. For example, you can use a promise to wait for the event OR generate another event, say `doneReadFile` and only then send the next event. Usually, this is not the case for a generic (distributed) environment.

If event generation does not care about how long it took to handle events, you can still use the above approach but check for the intermediate event `doneReadFile` in the next event handler (login/logout). This can be achieved by implementing some kind of [polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682622/using-setinterval-to-do-simplistic-continuous-polling) or [busy-wait/sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)