# Node.js adding html content in to a ejs page

Tags: node.js

is there a way to add HTML code to an already existing e.j.s. page to a specific line in the file?

I want to add a block of code only when a condition in the server file is met.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682622/using-setinterval-to-do-simplistic-continuous-polling .

Comment: What is an "ejs page"? Because it can't be both "ejs" and "a page": do you mean the EJS _template code_, before that gets rendered, or do you "the resulting page", _after_ the EJS got rendered? Because if you mean the former, then yes, EJS supports [conditional rendering](https://github.com/mde/ejs?tab=readme-ov-file#example) just fine. And if the latter: just do the former, instead? No reason to manipulate a page after rendering, just have the correct template code in place to _generate_ the page you need.