# How can i insert to mysql database and load with same function results to <select>-> <option>?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select, insert

I'm interested about Jquery and ajax to use with php&mysql.

I have been reading articles about loading intervall like 10 seconds. But that is not working with my page. (in select with 1000ms loading does load data every one second and unselects my option -box (i dont have idea how can i load that only if content changes..))..

I have page:

```
 <input type=text name=add_version value=>
 <input type=submit name=add value=add>
```

and

```
<select name=version>
<option><option>
<option value=1>v1.0</option>
<option value=2>v1.1.0</option>
</select>
```

How can i insert with ajax that "add_version" and load that same data to  with one "submit" button?

or

does somebody have result for that loading content only when data changes in my MySQL DB?

thanks for help!

Comment: edit: i would need that automatic page reload too (with option when: data have been changed).

Comment: You'll need to narrow down your question- you talk about MySQL, functions, jquery/AJAX, Polling, and only provide some rudimentary HTML to work from.

Comment: Hi, I only mean that i load / update new results from mysql. I dont know how jquery / ajax functions works with autoupdate (with 4sec intervall) and how that loads only new results to <option></option>.

Answer (score 0):

With your comment clarification, I think you're looking for ***Long Polling***.  There are plugins that can do that for you, but I'm not sure how you want to go about it, so here are a couple of places to start looking at how you can.

- [Facebook-like Realtime Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification)
- [How to implement COMET with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)
- [Google "ajax long polling"](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript%20long%20polling#hl=en&safe=off&pwst=1&sa=X&ei=ZRXnT5KvCOiemQWbn4j7Cg&ved=0CAYQvwUoAQ&q=ajax%20long%20polling&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=58c0f6de0f1c3337&biw=1398&bih=721)

Was doing some additional research, and came across this most [excellent tutorial about using node.js](http://www.nodebeginner.org/)

Comment: Thanks, i found ajax script wich reload with interval in <select></select>. Only bad with that was refresh interval can't select <option> because 2sec refresh deactivated always selecting.. I try to exam your links. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, and remember, thanks on SO means accepting an answer :)