# MySQL callback to the web-app

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to figure out the best way possible to notify my web-application of database changes. The way I'm doing it now, is that I've got separate MySQL table with a counter.

Now, when some database action happens in table Foo, a trigger is adding up the counter.
The web-app then polls every 5 seconds the server to check out, if something has happened (counter number has changed) and if so, refresh the data in app.

What I would like, is that I would be able to do callback/notify from MySQL to the server and from there to the web-app so that I don't need to poll the server frequently. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: try http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/real-time-monitoring-php-applications-with-websockets-and-node-js/ with http://meteor.com/ realtime php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How does facebook, gmail send the real time notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification)
You can't notify your application directly from MySQL, but there are some solutions to save bandwith and load of your server.

Answer (score 0):

one way of handling this - would be to either implement the observer pattern yourself or simply use a pubsub messaging option (ZMQ/AMQ/RabbitMQ/Redis etc) - when the initial database action takes place (ensure that the transaction has committed), publish the message to the topic on the pubusb tool - your application can  subscribe to the pubsub tool and receive messages when there is a DB change.

Hope it helps.