# Real time web update client to client

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I'm so curious real time web application like Facebook uses (eg. Friends Notifications) My question is what particular javascript code or existing framework I can use if theres any existing out there. Regards

Comment: Take a look at Comet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). There's [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for .NET

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at websockets.

A description:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

And a framework to use:
http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

That technique called as server push.Among them Comet is widley used and for `PHP`

> [**Pusher – Who I work for-**](http://pusher.com/)

[Here is the real time list](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide)

> Messaging: with focus on delivery to clients (e.g. Web Browsers)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access this technology is to use a framework.
We have used http://www.pusher.com in some projects with good results.

Answer (score 0):

This project is very nice, too:

http://socketo.me/

and its pure php

Answer (score 0):

also have look at this
its long polling
its very simpele
but its not better then socket.io 
http://www.screenr.com/SNH

Comment: i found that long polling technique is good. But is that stressful to server? When that polling technique needs to do some request every 1 second with setTimeout() function?

Comment: if every 1 second its short polling and it sucks long polling is faster and better

Answer (score 0):

There is http://www.asp.net/signalr, it uses the best service for the connection, e.g. If websocket is available, then it'll use websocket, othwerwise it will use other techniques like polling (the worst technique).

Another one is http://nodejs.org/, I don't know how it works, but it seems a good option. I think it uses websocket too.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Friends Notifications uses push technology.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

> Push, or server push, describes a style of Internet-based communication where the request for a given transaction is initiated by the publisher or central server. It is contrasted with pull, where the request for the transmission of information is initiated by the receiver or client.

[You can read more about the way it works technically using Comet following this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086448/1044644)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is AngularJS (http://anuglarjs.org). This is a newer technology developed by someone within Google and seems to hold many promises in web application development.

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor JS](http://www.meteor.com/) is also a nice library for realtime updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use setinterval() in JS, and an ajax function to check if there are new messages in your database (not seen by the current user), if so show them as new.
PP: you'll need to get to know some jquery and php, but overall creating it yourself gives you all the flexibility and a lot easier bug fixing