# How to get a Facebook like notification system in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications, diaspora

Hey how to make a notification system like Facebook or diaspora in rails.

I had tried making activity feed but that was not the thing I wanted I want an exactly same feature like this websites have.

I have a simple app Where there are two types of users buyers and sellers

I want to notify the seller whenever a buyer comment on their products.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at here is a `server push` implementation. That means when some notification/action happens in the server, it should push a notification to your rails app. The difference with @manju's answer is, its proposing a a solution based on your clients browser will call the server periodically for new notifications.

There are two main ways to do this.

**1 - Using some third party SASS solutions.** (easy way, but cost money ;))

[Fire base](https://www.firebase.com/) , allows you to send push notifications to clients.

[pusher](https://pusher.com/) is another provider offers the same kind of functionalists.

Read  their documentations, normally each of them have gems you can easily integrate to your rails app.

**2 - Implement your own push server**

You can implement your own push server with rails, and integrate to your app.

[Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) is a one option,

But more exiting thing is **Rails5** will have **Action Cable** which tries to solve the same issue. [action cable gem](https://github.com/rails/actioncable)

and there are articles showing action cable with rails4 apps (you dont have to wait till rails5 comes out) , but I haven't used it personally yet.

HTH

Comment: thanks @sameera207 . am not looking for a real time notification. i know it's stupid but yeah i want the user to refresh the browser to see new notifications.

Comment: I think you wanted to use SAAS (Software As A Service) instead of SASS (CSS extension language)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does it using *comet techniques.*

Here are some of the helpful links

[Link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

[Link2](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg30/index.html)

[Link3](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/05/the-forever-frame-technique/)

Here is the theory how facebook does

- Facebook works by polling the server for any changes.
- Facebook page will make ajax request to server and the ajax request will have much time out
- But in the server-side in the API in server it will constantly poll DB server if anything has changed by constantly checking the activity log table in database ..if a change has been found it will return the result till then it will poll the DB
- Once Ajax request is complete it will recursively try again.

Here is a code snippet  - Client side

```
function doPoll() {
   $.get("events.php", {}, function(result) {
      $.each(result.events, function(event) { //iterate over the events
          //do something with your event
      });
      doPoll(); 
      //this effectively causes the poll to run again as
      //soon as the response comes back
   }, 'json'); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
       timeout: 1000*60//set a global AJAX timeout of a minute
    });
    doPoll(); // do the first poll
});
```

Here is a code-snippet in server side:

```
while(!has_event_happened()) {
   sleep(5);
}

echo json_encode(get_events());
```

you can find it in much detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086448/5132539)

you can actually adopt this approach according to your needs

Comment: thanks @manju but i want something simple just notifications in a dropdown form.My needs are just that when a user comment on another user post they need to be notify with a number on the notification icon,with a notification in a drop-down for...sorry actually am a newbie that's why got in so much deep

Comment: @Denialsmith - you can use the same logic...but let the API return number of comments and shows that in icon...that's it ...But logic is comet