# How the Web Whatsapp Sends the message?

Tags: android, ios, html, websocket, whatsapp

I have been trying to inspect the whatsapp messages. I know Web WhatsApp uses the WebSockets. I can see some of data. But when I send message it just comes up with Binary coded data. It doesn't send XHR request. Then how does it sends message ?

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/c91yx5

Thank you!

Comment: They probably use GCM or Firebase, I don't know much about them but they're a good place to start.

Comment: But how it's sending the message ? I mean in what type of request ? @CookieMonster

Comment: Maybe this helps: "How does facebook, gmail send the real time notification?" https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086380/1066234 I also see "serviceworker.js" in the Developer console when using Whatsapp.