# What do top iOS apps use for live notifications server-side?

Tags: ios, node.js

This seems like a simple question to me, but it's one I simply can't find a good answer for: what do the top iOS apps (I'm talking Twitter, Facebook) use for live pushed data? Instead of polling an API for changes - real-time data updates, which I assume they have to have a method for.

My understanding is that the main solution is APNs (Apple Push Notifications) but I can't find any notable mention of apps using it... and have found only sparse support for NodeJS.

I'm deciding between that, and MQTT messages that trigger an API call. But I'm posting this question mainly because, in the back of my head, I think there's something I'm missing completely.

Thanks much for any information at all, or even pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of iOS apps send millions of push notifications each day; Facebook and Twitter included.

Comment: You misunderstand the question... I'm not talking about push notifications on the device, but remote push notifications from the server to the client/

Comment: Yes, all those apps use remote push notifications to send updates from the server to the client

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have said "thousands of iOS apps are sent millions of push notifications..."

Comment: Understood... guess that answers this then! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) its really got but only for iOS and Android

[AirNotifier](https://airnotifier.github.io/) supports iOS, Android and Windows

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification) is a useful stackoverflow post for you.

happy coding!