# how to create a web notification when detecting activity in the database in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create web notifications like those used by facebook when we receive a message, and create the notification, but how can I send it every time I detect a new record in my database?

my notification is the following

```js
<script src="https://pushjs.org/scripts/push.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
Push.create("Tienes un nuevo ticket", {
    body: "$funcionario tiene una incidendi",
    icon: '/icon.png',
    timeout: 4000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.focus();
        this.close();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very broad. You should try to solve the problem yourself and come back here when you have specific challenges that you could use help with.

Comment: This should help you with your research https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086448/1857971

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your can trigger a function in PHP when database is updated (Unless you can access a function where it is updating database).

You can write a CRON function/Poll function to check the database every few seconds and  trigger the notification when you see the change.

Comment: how is the cron used?

Comment: Please google it. It is easy to find a lot of tuts. :)

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 solution 
using cron job
or using nodejs

search in google about cronjob