# Flutter/Dart - Schedule a Mysql Query to run every few minutes?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, scheduled-tasks

I want to check user's posts every few minutes to see if anyone has replied and update a Text widget to show the number of new messages. This would be just like the way Facebook lets you know whenever there is any new activity. I'm using a mysql database as my backend. Was thinking to simply make a mysql query every few minutes. Does anybody know how Facebook does it? Would it be better if I moved over to something like NodeJS instead of making expensive MYSQL database queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **package**: https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

or

If you need something more reliable, **implement natively** for each platform, and use MethodChannel to integrate with Flutter.

For Android: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

For iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler

As for **How Facebook does it**, check this: [How does facebook, gmail send the real time notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086380/how-does-facebook-gmail-send-the-real-time-notification)